# iPad Custom Table Cells with plists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I've been following an excellent guide on how to create basic custom table cells and populate them via a plist.  The problem i've run into is the guide is written for iPhone, and i'm developing an app on iPad, one of the key issues is when creating the project, the guide uses a Navigation based template for iPhone, where iPad isn't selectable.  Later on the guide it says to add outputs to this controller.

I tried following the guide using a Window based template for iPad, but have run into some problems when connecting the output.  In particular where I add my 'customTableViewCell' outlet to the 'RootViewController' (which is a UITableController) - in my iPad project, it's just a 'UIViewController'

Is there an easy was to solve this? or is developing it on iPad a totally different tutorial?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad, the Split-View format is really for navigation. It has a root view controller that is a tableview. You might have good luck starting with that template.
In the Interface Builder, you can add UITableView by dragging it onto the view.